# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, datetime, cultureinfo

I try to convert string to `datetime` but each time I get :

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Code is:

```
string format = "dd/MM/yyyy";

obj.TransDate = DateTime.ParseExact(lbl_TransDate.Text.Split('/')[0] + "/" + lbl_TransDate.Text.Split('/')[1] + "/" + lbl_TransDate.Text.Split('/')[2], format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

When I debug the date which I try to parse it is : `12/4/2012`

Comment: out of plain curiosity, why not just `DateTime.ParseExact(lbl_TransDate.Text, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`?

Comment: :)
it is not my code , just i test this part

Comment: Did you check it with this code `DateTime dt;
string Temp1 = "Your Date";
if (DateTime.TryParse(Temp1, out dt))
{
     // If it is a valid date
     string date = dt.ToShortDateString();
     string time = dt.ToShortTimeString();
}
`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The desired format is

```
string format = "dd/M/yyyy";
```

I don't understand a thing though, why split an concatenate the string, since you would obtain the same thing?

If the input is *12/4/2012*, after the split by *'/'*, you'll get 12, 4, 2012 and then concatenate them back to obtain "12/4/2012". Why this?

Also, if you really need that split, you can store in into an array so you don't need to split it 3 times:

```
var splits = lbl_TransDate.Text.Split('/');
DateTime.ParseExact(splits[0] + "/" + splits[1] + "/" + splits[2], ...);
```

If you don't trust the input, the splits array might not be of Length = 3, and more of it, you can use *DateTime.TryParseExact*

**EDIT** You can use the overload with multiple formats 
So if the input might be *12/4/2012 or 12/04/2012*, you can give both formats

```
var formats = new[] {"dd/M/yyyy","dd/MM/yyyy"};
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("12/4/2012", formats, 
                                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                        System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
```

Comment: the `informix` date "dd/MM/yyyy".

Comment: `The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.` when i try yours.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the other answers that it looks like your doing a lot to solve what should be a simple problem. I'd use the British date format from the culture info.

```
var convertedDay = DateTime.Parse("12/04/2010", new CultureInfo("en-GB").DateTimeFormat);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying `MM` when you only have a single digit. Either use just a single `M`, or pad left with zero using the `PadLeft` function.

The following code demonstrates this with both `dd` and `MM` padded as desired

```
string format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
string mydate = "12/4/2012";
DateTime t = DateTime.ParseExact(mydate.Split('/')[0].PadLeft(2,'0') + "/" + 
                                 mydate.Split('/')[1].PadLeft(2,'0') + "/" + 
                                mydate.Split('/')[2], format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Output is:

```
12/04/2012 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you add the following in your web config

```
<system.web>
<globalization culture="en-AU"/>...
```

See the following for the correct culture country code

http://sharpertutorials.com/list-of-culture-codes/